# Circular shift of vector by distance n

Tags: r, vector

Say I have

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

and I want b to be derived from a by shifting it in direction "left" by distance 1

```
b
# [1] 2 3 1
```

By derivation I mean you either:

1. Pass "a" into a function that spits out "b"
2. You use some sort of indexing short had which does that.
3. `b <- c(2, 3, 1)`, for example, is not a solution I'm looking for

What would be elegant/efficient ways to do that?

Comment: this isn't enough information to see the pattern you are going for. In this case `b <- a[c(2,3,1)]` but maybe you're looking for something else.

Comment: @plafort hey thanks for the comment - I tried to add more detail to the question - does it help

Comment: it does, I'll post an answer

Comment: take Ananda's answer, mine was too case-specific `b <- a[c(2:length(a),1)]`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can make use of `head` and `tail` to create a function like this:

```
shifter <- function(x, n = 1) {
  if (n == 0) x else c(tail(x, -n), head(x, n))
}
```

Usage:

```
a <- 1:4

shifter(a)
# [1] 2 3 4 1

shifter(a, 2)
# [1] 3 4 1 2
```

(Or, `library(SOfun); shifter(a)` where you can get `SOfun` from [here](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun)).